# Resize Command prompt on bat file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

Is there any way to start a **.bat** file and resize the window to a custom size from the code? I don't want to change it from the **cmd.exe** file because i want it to be dynamic (I want to make a few **.bat** with different sizes)

```
@ECHO OFF

rem **Something to resize here**

rem Rest of the code...

pause
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
mode con:cols=80 lines=40
```

which I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/584027/can-you-dynamically-resize-windows-command-line-window). You can modify the numerical values to your specific needs.

I can't test it right now, because I'm on Linux, but I know I used to do the same thing using `mode con`.

Comment: This works, but a lot of people use 800+ lines in a scrollable window of only 40 or so lines. I don't think you can do this with the mode command.